# Amplitude of single-mode field in a cavity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, quantum-optics

I have two contradictory result about the amplitude of single mode field when it is quantized

- In C. Gerry and P. Knight's *Introductory quantum optics*, the amplitude is given by 
  $$\sqrt{\frac{2\omega^2}{V\epsilon_0}},$$
  which puts the hamiltonian of radiation in the cavity at $H=\frac{1}{2}(p^2 + \omega^2q^2)$ and the electric field as $E=\sqrt{\frac{2\omega^2}{V\epsilon_0}} q(t)\sin{kz} \ \  \hat{x}$
- There is also another suggestion in Alain Aspect's lecture [Quantum Optics - Canonical quantization of a single mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AatF8FyGpI0&list=PL2jykFOD1AWaYcXzYm08-pM0S0QNzmFIU&index=7) on youtube, where Aspect suggests that amplitude is 
  $$\sqrt{\frac{\hbar\omega}{V\epsilon_0}},$$
  which puts the hamiltonian at $H=\hbar\omega|\alpha|^2$ and the electric field as $E = i \sqrt{\frac{\hbar\omega}{V\epsilon_0}} \alpha(t)\sin{kz}\ \ \textbf{e}$

Which one is correct? or is there what make me confused?

Comment: I have reformatted your question to fit our site standards, including in particular [the requirement of unambiguous links to any references you introduce](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11400/what-is-the-policy-for-linking-e-g-why-should-we-link-to-abstract-pages-rathe). If you have a suitable link to the Coursera lecture you mention, then you can edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "correct" or an "incorrect" choice. The two are just two different, equivalent ways to handle the book-keeping of the different constants involved in the formalism, and different conventions in terms of working with real-valued quadratures (like Gerry and Knight's $q$ and $p$) or complex-valued ones (like Aspect's $\alpha$).

Neither choice has any impact on the content of the physics.

Comment: Thank you very much